# snow inside of fridge

Tags: refrigerator

My refrigerator has started to 'snow' up inside and is freezing some of the food. Why is this? It is in a cabinet with about 1 inch space on top. I have turned the thermometer down from the one set as default. What might be the problem. Is it because it is in a cabinet?

Comment: You should be able to look up the minimum installation clearances (top, sides, and back) in the user's manual. You should be able to find a copy online with the fridge model number if you don't have the original.

Comment: What kind of refrigerator do you have and what model is it ? Might want to google it since perhaps there might be other people may have the same problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You should look to see if air flow vents around the bottom of the refrigerator are clogged up with dirt and dust bunnies. If so clean that up with a vacuum cleaner. It may be well to remove the unit from the cabinet to clean out the whole area.

Also this problem can be brought on by failure of the air circulation fan in the refrigerator.

Some questions remain:

1. Is this installation new and you are just experiencing this problem?
2. In the past has there been successful use of the refrigerator in its current configuration all through a year or more of ambient temperature cycles?
3. Is this a refrigerator without a freezer compartment?

Comment: Michael is right on with this answer! + if a older and clean air flow it may be low on charge. But check for the dust bunnies or even a dead mouse stopping the fan in one case I found.